# SQL Server 2012 T-SQL count number of words between elements of two sets

Tags: sql, sql-server, text, pattern-matching

I have two sets of elements, let's say they are these words:

- set 1: "nuclear", "fission", "dirty" and
- set 2: "device", "explosive"

In my database, I have a text column (`Description`) which contains a sentence or two. I would like to find any records where `Description` contains both an element from set 1 followed by an element from set 2, where the two elements are separated by four words or less. For simplicity, counting (spaces-1) will count words between the two elements.

I'd prefer it if a solution didn't require the installation of anything like CLR functions for regular expression. Rather, if this could be done with a user-defined table function, it would make deployment simpler.

Does this sound possible?

Comment: You need a full text index, using the `contains` keyword.  You can start here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx.

Comment: Another way to approach this is with a split function (UDF) to generate a word-table from your Description field, which can then be joined to your keyword sets, and the matching results counted.

Comment: Thank you, @GordonLinoff! That is a great solution. Just for reference here's how I added the full text index, and example of the contains keyword:

CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG IndexName WITH ACCENT_SENSITIVITY = OFF;

ALTER TABLE TableName ADD ID INT IDENTITY(1,1);

ALTER TABLE TableName ALTER COLUMN ID INT NOT NULL;

ALTER TABLE TableName ADD CONSTRAINT ID_PK PRIMARY KEY clustered(ID);

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON TableName (Description LANGUAGE 1033) KEY INDEX ID_PK ON IndexName WITH STOPLIST = SYSTEM;

select * from TableName where contains(Description,'NEAR ((nuclear, device), 4, TRUE)')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, but i do not think it will preform well with millions of rows.
I have a solution here that handles about 10 000 rows in 2 sec and 100 000 rows in about 20 sec on our server. It also requires the famous [DelimitedSplit8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) sql table function from SQLServerCentral:

```
DECLARE @set1 VARCHAR(MAX) = 'nuclear, fission, dirty';
DECLARE @set2 VARCHAR(MAX) = 'device, explosive';

WITH GetDistances AS 
(
    SELECT 
    DubID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID)
    , Distance = dbo.[cf_ValueSetDistance](s.Description, @set1, @set2)
    , s.ID
    ,s.Description 
    FROM #sentences s
    JOIN dbo.cf_DelimitedSplit8K(@set1, ',') s1 ON s.Description LIKE '%' + RTRIM(LTRIM(s1.Item)) + '%'
    JOIN dbo.cf_DelimitedSplit8K(@set2, ',') s2 ON s.Description LIKE '%' + RTRIM(LTRIM(s2.Item)) + '%'
) SELECT Distance, ID, Description FROM GetDistances WHERE DubID = 1 AND Distance BETWEEN 1 AND 4;
--10 000 rows: 2sec
--100 000 rows: 20sec
```

[image]

**Test data generator**

```
--DROP TABLE #sentences
CREATE TABLE #sentences
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    , Description VARCHAR(100)
);

GO
--CREATE 10000 random sentences that are 100 chars long
SET NOCOUNT ON;
WHILE((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #sentences) < 10000)
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @randomWord VARCHAR(100) = '';
    SELECT TOP 100 @randomWord = @randomWord + ' ' + Item FROM  dbo.cf_DelimitedSplit8K('nuclear fission dirty device explosive On the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of the moment, so blinded by desire, that they cannot foresee the pain and trouble that are bound to ensue; and equal blame belongs to those who fail in their duty through weakness of will, which is the same as saying through shrinking from toil and pain. These cases are perfectly simple and easy to distinguish. In a free hour, when our power of choice is untrammelled and when nothing prevents our being able to do what we like best, every pleasure is to be welcomed and every pain avoided. But in certain circumstances and owing to the claims of duty or the obligations of business it will frequently occur that pleasures have to be repudiated and annoyances accepted. The wise man therefore always holds in these matters to this principle of selection: he rejects pleasures to secure other greater pleasures, or else he endures pains to avoid worse pains', ' ') ORDER BY NEWID();

    INSERT INTO #sentences
    SELECT @randomWord
END

SET NOCOUNT OFF;
```

**Function 1 - cf_ValueSetDistance**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[cf_ValueSetDistance]
(
    @value VARCHAR(MAX)
    , @compareSet1 VARCHAR(MAX)
    , @compareSet2 VARCHAR(MAX)
) 
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN

SET @value = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@value, '.', ''), ',', ''), '?', '');
DECLARE @distance INT;

DECLARE @sentence TABLE( WordIndex INT, Word VARCHAR(MAX) );
DECLARE @set1 TABLE(Word VARCHAR(MAX) );
DECLARE @set2 TABLE(Word VARCHAR(MAX) );

INSERT INTO @sentence
SELECT ItemNumber, RTRIM(LTRIM(Item)) FROM dbo.cf_DelimitedSplit8K(@value, ' ')

INSERT INTO @set1
SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(Item)) FROM dbo.cf_DelimitedSplit8K(@compareSet1, ',')

IF(EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @sentence s JOIN @set1 s1 ON s.Word = s1.Word))
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO @set2
    SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(Item)) FROM dbo.cf_DelimitedSplit8K(@compareSet2, ',');

    IF(EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @sentence s JOIN @set2 s2 ON s.Word = s2.Word))
    BEGIN

        WITH Set1 AS (
            SELECT s.WordIndex, s.Word FROM @sentence s
            JOIN @set1 s1 ON s1.Word = s.Word
        ), Set2 AS
        (
            SELECT s.WordIndex, s.Word FROM @sentence s
            JOIN @set2 s2 ON s2.Word = s.Word
        )

        SELECT @distance = MIN(ABS(s2.WordIndex - s1.WordIndex)) FROM Set1 s1, Set2 s2  
    END

END

RETURN @distance;

END
```

**Function 2 - DelimitedSplit8K**
(No need to even try to understand this code, this is an extremely fast function for splitting a string to a table, written by several talented people):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[cf_DelimitedSplit8K]
        (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
 RETURN
--===== "Inline" CTE Driven "Tally Table" produces values from 0 up to 10,000...
     -- enough to cover NVARCHAR(4000)
  WITH E1(N) AS (
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
 cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "base" CTE and limits the number of rows right up front
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
                 SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@pString),0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
                ),
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just once for each delimiter)
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t WHERE SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter
                ),
cteLen(N1,L1) AS(--==== Return start and length (for use in substring)
                 SELECT s.N1,
                        ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter,@pString,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000)
                   FROM cteStart s
                )
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final element when no delimiter is found.
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY l.N1),
        Item       = SUBSTRING(@pString, l.N1, l.L1)
   FROM cteLen l;
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know anything about performance, but this could be done with cross apply and two temporary tables.

```
--initialize word set data
DECLARE @set1 TABLE (wordFromSet varchar(n))
DECLARE @set2 TABLE (wordFromSet varchar(n))

INSERT INTO @set1 SELECT 'nuclear' UNION SELECT 'fission' UNION SELECT 'dirty'
INSERT INTO @set2 SELECT 'device' UNION SELECT 'explosive' 

SELECT *
FROM MyTable m
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT wordFromSet
    ,LEN(SUBSTRING(m.Description, 1, CHARINDEX(wordFromSet, m.Description))) - LEN(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(m.Description, 1, CHARINDEX(wordFromSet, m.Description)),' ', '')) AS WordPosition
    FROM @set1
    WHERE m.Description LIKE '%' + wordFromSet + '%'
) w1
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT wordFromSet
    ,LEN(SUBSTRING(m.Description, 1, CHARINDEX(wordFromSet, m.Description))) - LEN(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(m.Description, 1, CHARINDEX(wordFromSet, m.Description)),' ', '')) AS WordPosition
    FROM @set2
    WHERE m.Description LIKE '%' + wordFromSet + '%'
) w2
WHERE w2.WordPosition - w1.WordPosition <= treshold
```

Essentially it will only return rows from MyTable that have at least a word from both sets, and for these rows it will calculate which word position it holds by calculating the difference in length between the substring that ends at the words position and the same substring with spaces removed.

Answer (score 0):

I am adding a new answer, even if my old one has been accepted and I can see you went for the "FULL TEXT INDEX".

I have looked at the answer @Louis gave, and I think it was clever to use "CROSS APPLY". His answer beats the performance of mine. The only problem is that his code will only compare from the first instance of a word. This made me want to try to combine his answer with the split function I used ([DelimitedSplit8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) from SQLServerCentral).

This results in a remarkable performance boost, I have tested this on 1 million rows, and the result was almost instant:

- My old answer: 5min
- @Louis answer: 2min
- New answer: 3sec

This do not beet the "FULLTEXT INDEX" performance wise, but it at least supports the word search combination specification you provided in a relatively effective way.

```
DECLARE @set1 TABLE (Word VARCHAR(50))
DECLARE @set2 TABLE (Word VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @set1 SELECT 'nuclear' UNION SELECT 'fission' UNION SELECT 'dirty'
INSERT INTO @set2 SELECT 'device'UNION SELECT 'explosive' 

SELECT * FROM #sentences s
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT * FROM @set1 s1
    JOIN dbo.cf_DelimitedSplit8K(s.Description, ' ') split ON split.Item = s1.Word
) s1
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT * FROM @set2 s2
    JOIN dbo.cf_DelimitedSplit8K(s.Description, ' ') split ON split.Item = s2.Word
) s2
WHERE ABS(s1.ItemNumber - s2.ItemNumber) <= 4;
```

*Look at my old answer for the code for the dbo.cf_COM_DelimitedSplit8K function.*